# vim: remap control commands to space commands

Tags: vim

I want to make vim be free of Ctrl+KEY commands. I want to remap those commands to Space & KEY (which means two strokes).

In another words, if I hit Space (push and release), then in half of the second I hit D, my view will scroll (like hitting Ctrl+D). Is it possible to remap all Ctrl-commands in one go?

Comment: Or at least probably not well ;-)

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I want to make my Vim free of keystrokes when you have to press two keys in the same time. It takes me more time to use it, than all great one letter commands. Additionally, Ctrl key is two far away in my opinion for VIM fingering.

Comment: Might I recommend remapping Caps Lock to Ctrl. It was one of the best decisions I ever made.

Comment: @Conner How did you remap it? In vim or in X server? Can you post your code?

Comment: @TomekWyderka X server using ~/.Xmodmap

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can cycle through the alphabet and map each letter for every mode:

```
let alphabet = map(range(char2nr('a'),char2nr('z')),'nr2char(v:val)')
for letter in alphabet
  exe "noremap! <space>".letter." <C-".letter.">"
  exe "noremap <space>".letter." <C-".letter.">"
endfor
```

However, this will likely produce unexpected consequences down the road.

Comment: It works for me! But I will take just subset of alphabet. Thanks!